# How do I use a increment operator in parallel in OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I want to increment `count` variable in all of my threads if a condition is met. Is there a better way to do this other than enclosing the `count` variable in a critical block or using `count[]` as an array?

```
pragma omp parallel for num_threads(number_of_threads)

int id = omp_get_thread_num();    
for(i=1; i < ht; i++) { 
    for(j=1; j < wd; j++) {
                            
            // Some random code
                            
            double mag = sqrt(a[i] * a[i] + b[j] * b[j]); 
                
            if(mag > 100) {         
                  #pragma omp critical 
                  { 
                        count++;
                  }
            } else {
                  // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for OpenMP's `reduction` variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Mark's comment, get rid of the `critical` block and replace the `omp parallel` block with

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(number_of_threads) reduction(+:count)
```

This gives each thread a private `count` which are incremented independently then summed upon exit from the `omp parallel` block